# Oracle ords 3.0.12 deploy on weblogic server 10.3

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-apex, weblogic-10.x, oracle-ords

I use an Oracle RDBMS 18c where APEX 18.2 is installed on it. I also have a WebLogic 10.3 on a different server. Environment :

windows server 2008: ords 3.0.12 and weblogic 10.3
windows server 2019: db and apex

I have completely configured db, Oracle apex at one server A, ords w/SQL DEVELOPER and deploy it on weblogic on a different server B. My URL is working but it showing me that i have used wrong image directory path (not showing apex graphics). I call image directory through a NETWORK Map Drive from server A which is called as "X:\apex\images"
I have tried all way i.e. "X:\apex\images", "X:\apex\images\", "X:\apex\images" but failed,

Error:

"There is a problem with your environment because the Application Express files have not been loaded. Please verify that you have copied the images directory to your application server as instructed in the Installation Guide. In addition, please verify that your image prefix path is correct. Your current path is /i/ (it should contain both starting and ending forward slashes, such as the default /i/). Use the SQL script reset_image_prefix.sql if you need to change it."

Please help me that how to put images file path from remote server for creation of i.war that will deploy on weblogic (java -jar ords.war static **<remote_server>**\images\)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaVrL.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: 3.0.12 is now 3 years old. You should use a newer version.

Comment: yes i move to ORDS 19.2 but i am running it as standalone this time. Please suggest which is best server to deploy it? Weblogic or Tomcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is a good hint:

```
please verify that you have copied the images directory to your application server
```

Which is the exact opposite of what you did:

> I call image directory through a NETWORK Map Drive

Try to copy the files to a directory on the aaplication server.

OR make triple-sure that the service account in which this stuff runs can access the network location: Just because "administrator" does have a mapped drives for himself, this does not mean  has the same. This goes for the access rights, too. Usually you can get around the mapping-error by using UNC paths (`\\<SERVER>\<RESSOURCE>\<PATH>`).